# Connect NIFI on premise and NIFI Cloud Site to Site

Tags: apache-nifi

We are currently trying to set up a NIFI site to Site communication between on premise Nifi and a Nifi cloud cluster(2 nodes). After deploying the certificate on the nifi host in the cloud, we did try to restart the nifi host one at the time. We get the following error:

[NIFI error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1DNg.png)

Could you please help us.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

TLS uses *certificates* to contain the public component of the *key pair* (a public and private value which are interrelated mathematically). These certificates (almost always in X.509 v3 format) have properties expressed through `OID` (Object Identifiers). One of these is "Extended Key Usage", which dictates the *roles* that this certificate can be used for. The error is stating that the certificate you're trying to use does not specify the "web server" EKU, but does specify (at least) one other, so NiFi refuses to accept this certificate as a web server. You'll need to generate the certificate with the proper EKU values (both "client" and "server" are required) to use as a NiFi certificate.